# Flutter - How to retrieve data from firebase and save in sharedpreference

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to retrieve user name, photourl and email from user and save this info to shared preferences.

What I tried so far:

```
  Future<bool> _saveNameAndEmailPreference(String name, String email) async {
  final pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  await pref.setString('name', name);
  await pref.setString('email', email);
  return pref.commit();
```

}

Firebase

```
DatabaseReference reference =
      FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("users").child(uid);
  reference.once().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapShot) {
    var keys = dataSnapShot.value.keys;
    var values = dataSnapShot.value;
    for (var key in keys) {
      Users userinformation = new Users(
        values[key]["name"],
        values[key]["email"],
        values[key]["photourl"],
      );

      userinformationList.add(userinformation);
    }
    setState(() {
      nametxt = userinformationList[0].name;
      emailtxt = userinformationList[1].email;
     _saveNameAndEmailPreference(nametxt, emailtxt);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Could you give use more infos about the problem you're having ? Your SharedPreferences management looks pretty okay from here

Comment: It is working fine. Sorry, i had other thing messing up the code